# Is FIBRE still in use in 2023?

Tags: p2p, fibre

I have read [Can someone please explain FIBRE to me like I'm 5 and why is it useful?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56485/can-someone-please-explain-fibre-to-me-like-im-5-and-why-is-it-useful) then https://bitcoinfibre.org/ and https://github.com/bitcoinfibre/bitcoinfibre.

**But I still do not understand, is it in use today in 2023 and where, how?**

My understanding is that it is not because https://github.com/bitcoinfibre/bitcoinfibre has had no commits since 16/01/2019 and it was set to read-only on 15/01/2020.
If it is not in use, what happend to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The public Bitcoin FIBRE network was shut down [“a year or two” before May 2022](https://twitter.com/TheBlueMatt/status/1530016523921698816). Some of the reasons were that block propagation became a lot faster after compact block relay ([BIP152](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0152.mediawiki)) was deployed to the network, and the cost and effort of operating FIBRE was mostly borne by one individual.

Comment: just few follow up questions. You say "public Bitcoin FIBRE network was shut down". Does that mean that there is/are some private ones ? If there are for what use are they used ?

Comment: Since it is an open-source project, it would be possible that e.g. some miners continue to run one. I don’t know whether that is actually the case.