# did FIBRE technology improve the pace of Mempool data(pending transactions) propagation in Bitcoin?

Tags: fibre

The FIBRE technology seems to transmit the mined blocks. I am wondering if this technology transmits pending transactions in the Mempool as well.

Comment: Your question appears to be asking about the present time, but [FIBRE was shut down in 2020 or 2021](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118059/5406).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am study the effect of that on before 2021. I am wondering what was the mechanism for that.

Comment: Reading https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/80927/5406 and https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/56494/5406 it seems that it was only used for block relay, but I don’t remember in detail. I’m gonna suggest to some people that might remember to take a look at this question.